# Error 500 for product page

Tags: error, http-error-500

after copy files into new server - magento shop working good, but when i goto in product page - i see HTTP ERROR or Internal server error HTTP 500, in admin panel - 
Index Management - re-index - good, Cache Storage Management also good - green status, in log - not error, how i can fix product page? can you tell me?

Comment: Did you check Magento logs only? Is there any logs from apache?

Comment: yes only magento, to apache log i not have access

Answer (score 2):

1. Could you try to refresh your cache (System -> Cache Management -> Flush Magento Cache)?
2. Could you try to disable flat tables for products?
   It can be done via updating System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend->Use Flat Catalog Category and Use Flat Catalog Product to No.

Comment: 1. done, and without problem
2. Disable flat rate? if in database, i can clear table in database

Comment: Not Flat rate. Using flat tables for products and categories.
I've updated the answer. Please don't do changes in DB. :)

Comment: Thanks, but this all have, Flat Catalog Category and  Use Flat Catalog Product on default - No. look my link: http://goo.gl/wtJs3r, whole site working good, only product page not working

Comment: I've opened it. Did you fix it? What was wrong?..